# Downloading files from FTP server causes them to have extra line breaks

Tags: ftp

When I download a file from our companies Linux FTP server it keeps adding extra line breaks to the file, so that the file is double spaced in a normal Windows editor.

I tried opening it in gvim for windows and this warrants a line-break as well as a "^M" at the end of every line, but does not insert the additional line character.

I realize this is probably a \n\r problem between Windows and Linux (I really thought that Windows didn't have issues reading \n\r's but I guess I was wrong).  I was just wondering if there was anyway I can configure my ftp client (filezilla) so that it removes these extra characters ("^M").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the default transfer type to Binary. If that doesn't work try setting it to Auto or ASCII.

Comment: Yup that did the trick Joe! +1 Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...